# Persistent encrypted bootable USB kali linux on Razer Blade Pro running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, encryption, kali-linux, usb-3

I've created a bootable usb3 running an encrypted persistence version of the latest kali linux. I've successfully booted up from 2 other machines; 1 running windows 10 and a 2015 razer blade. When I try to boot using my 2016 Razer Blade Pro the install will hang mid boot, freezing the computer forcing me to do a hard shut down. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You need more specifics.  'mid-boot' is vague.  Does the system complete POST?  Does it use GRUB?  Does the GRUB menu display?  Interrupt the auto-boot and edit the boot command.  Remove 'quiet' from the kernel line.  (Don't worry, changes aren't saved.)  Watch the boot process to see what module hangs.

Comment: Does the 2016 model have secure boot enabled?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, No, I disabled it in the BIOS so I can boot from the USB. I select encrypted persistence, the process starts (i can see the command lines running) but before it's finished and before it asks me to enter my password it freezes.

Comment: @Xalorous I apologize in advance if any of this is redundant, I'm a bit new, but how do I tell if it uses GRUB? I'm not sure what the GRUB menu looks like. The menu displays where I can select Encrypted Persistence. Also, how do I interrupt the auto-boot and edit the command? Thanks for any help and I'm sorry if these are novice questions.

Comment: If it uses grub boot loader, it'll show a menu for a few seconds (4 by default) and it'll say press 'e' to edit the boot choice.  If it doesn't show that menu, it's probably not grub, and it's outside my experience.  What I'm suggesting is that you force the boot loader (grub or otherwise) to show you the boot process messages on screen.  I'm actually surprised that Kali doesn't.  Backtrack (precursor to Kali) did.  I guess after the fork, they hid the boot messages.  I find it odd though, those messages are critical to troubleshooting.